# Where do I ask a question about a possible career path?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I had a question about the future of Citrix as potential career field, but wasn't sure where to ask it.

I ended up asking it on [Programmers SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/23344/whats-the-future-of-citrix), is there a better place for these types of questions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMO that's the correct place (at least within the Stack Exchange network).